# Need help for OpenCPU and igraph output format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, r, opencpu

My data Adjancy array is

```
var g = [[10, 2], [15, 0], [18, 3], [19, 6], [20, 8.5], [25, 10], [30, 9], [35, 8], [40, 5], [45, 6], [50, 2.5]]
```

and my OpenCPU code is

```
            ocpu.call("centralization.closeness", {graph: g}, function(res){
            // console.log(ocpu.seturl(res.output[0]));
            $http.get("//public.opencpu.org/"+res.output[0]+"/json").success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
```

this is giving error

> OpenCPU error HTTP 400 Not a graph object
>
> In call: centralization.closeness(graph = g)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`centralization.closeness` takes a graph object and not an array

**Suggestion**:

- convert the array to an adjacency matrix
- convert matrix to graph using `graph_from_adjacency_matrix`.
- pass resulting graph to `centralization.closeness`

**EDIT:** solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/bowofola/pskezhLq/2/

```js
var graph = [
  [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
];

//set CORS to call igraph package
ocpu.seturl("https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/igraph/R");

var graphSession;

$('#output').text(graph.toString());

$('#adjMatrix').click(function() {
  ocpu.call("graph_from_adjacency_matrix", {
    adjmatrix: graph,
    mode: 'directed',
    weighted: true
  }, function(session) {
    graphSession = session;
    //retrieve session console (async)
    graphSession.getConsole(function(outtxt) {
      $("#output").text(outtxt);
      $("#centralize").prop('disabled', false);
    });
  }).fail(function() {
    alert("Error: " + req.responseText);
  });
});

$('#centralize').click(function() {
  var centralizeReq = ocpu.call("centralization.closeness", {
    graph: graphSession,
    mode: "all",
    normalized: true
  }, function(centralizeSession) {
    centralizeSession.getConsole(function(outtxt) {
      $("#output").text(outtxt);
    });
  }).fail(function() {
    alert("Error: " + req.responseText);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.opencpu.org/opencpu-0.4.js"></script>

<div>
  <textarea name="" id="output" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>
  <br />
  <button id="adjMatrix">Graph From Adj</button>
  <button id="centralize" disabled>Centralize</button>
</div>
```

for more examples on using open cpu, head here: http://jsfiddle.net/user/opencpu/fiddles/

Comment: array is in adjacency matrix..... when i use "graph_from_adjacency_matrix" it gives me result in session.... but i cannot pass the session result into centralization.closeness as a graph object... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43930580/opencpu-error-http-400-not-a-graph-object

Comment: graph_from_adjacency_matrix print something like this
IGRAPH D-W- 14 119 -- \n+ attr: weight (e/n)\n+ edges:\n [1]  1-> 2  1-> 3  1-> 5  1-> 6  1->10  1->11  1->12  1->13  1->14  2-> 1\n[11]  2-> 3  2-

Comment: update the matrix in the question to the one in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43930580/opencpu-error-http-400-not-a-graph-object

Comment: Yes..... this is the point i was missing.....

( centralization.closeness(graph = x06eddb341a::.val ) this is what SHOULD be pass to another function... and it is done as shown in example provided by Brother Bowofola at https://jsfiddle.net/bowofola/pskezhLq/2/

Comment: One more small Advice...

i can rplot my Graph But i cannot view it on broweser (http://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/tmp/x03c8281217/graphics/last/png?width=100&height=100)

But i can view PNG if i access same URL like this (http://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/tmp/x03c8281217/graphics/last/png)

Comment: I have no idea bro. What format are you expecting...?

Comment: i m facing this same issues as describe here....... https://github.com/opencpu/opencpu/issues/200

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is it you expect OpenCPU to run? Currently you are running this code:

```
library(igraph)
g <- jsonlite::fromJSON('[[10, 2], [15, 0], [18, 3], [19, 6], [20, 8.5], [25, 10], [30, 9], [35, 8], [40, 5], [45, 6], [50, 2.5]]')
igraph::centralization.closeness(g)
```

When running this in R you will get the same error. You need to write a wrapper function which transforms the matrix into a type which can then be passed to `centralization.closeness`.

Comment: i cannot pass the session result into centralization.closeness as a graph object.  please view this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43930580/opencpu-error-http-400-not-a-graph-object

Comment: Can you include an example of the R code that you would like to run (without opencpu) that makes it easier to show how you would do this via opencpu.

Comment: you can look at this....http://www.orgnodes.com/open.html in the mean while i provide R code...

Comment: i m using angular JS to generate adjacency matrix and than converting the matrix into graph using "graph_from_adjacency_matrix" and than want to pass on that "output" as graph object into "closeness"

Comment: Basic R CODE IS g <- graph.adjacency(m,mode = "directed", weighted = TRUE)
    get.adjacency(g, attr="weight")
    
    print(g)
    w_closeness <- centralization.closeness(g)$res

Comment: ocpu.call("graph_from_adjacency_matrix", {adjmatrix: graph, mode:'directed', weighted:true}, function(res){
$http.get("//public.opencpu.org/"+res.output[0]).success(function(data) {
                    ocpu.call("centralization.closeness", {graph: data}, function(res){         $http.get("//public.opencpu.org/"+res.output[0]+"/json").success(function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        });
                    });                    
                });
            });

Comment: what ever value  i pass into "graph" param it gives me error
Unparsable argument: {0:[1,2,3],1[1,2,3]} what is the param value that param graph take in function centralization.closeness